# Returning a value from called shell script to calling perl script

Tags: shell

I have a shell script (say test.sh), which has the following content:

```
var1=$(sshpass -p pass ssh user@host "cd folder1; ./test.sh $1 $2;")
echo $var1
```

I can see it running and returning two values (-1 and 0). Now I am calling it from a perl file:

```
my $ssh=system("./Test.sh $arg1 $arg2");
```

But here I can see that only value is being displayed is 0. -1 is not being displayed. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gather that the output of `test.sh` is a *string* `0` or `-1`, since exit values from scripts can't be negative. And you use Perl's `system()` function if you want to execute a command and *don't* want to capture its output.

Try instead:

```
my $ssh=`./Test.sh $arg1 $arg2`;
```

Comment: My pleasure! Please feel free to close this question by clicking the checkmark beside my answer.

Comment: @GourabSengupta You also could read: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: by me the `qx(some command)` is more readable. But (OFC) this is only personal taste :)